# Is a battle dancer dip worth it for bard?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, bard

Or is it just more trouble then it's worth. If it is are there other methods for getting charisma to AC? Mechanically I simply want to make a character that is as SAD as possible in this case charisma. So what would be the easiest and fastest way to do it using a bard chassis?

Comment: For this to get any sort of quality answers you need to explain what "worth it" is to you, your character goals and the level you are regarding as success. Right now it seems like you are just asking for a list of of adding CHA mod to AC.

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith [To be clear, a short list of ways to add one's Charisma bonus to AC would be in the site's wheelhouse](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6442/8610). I'd argue for a more specific question, though, like *What's the easiest and soonest way for a bard to gain his Charisma bonus to AC while still keeping X [fill in the blank] bard abilities?* or something.

Answer (score 2):

From consulting the invaluable [X Stat To Y Bonus tool](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?125732-3-x-X-stat-to-Y-bonus), I'd say the best ways to get CHA to AC for a Bard would be either [Arcane Duelist 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20150911052408/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/re/20030224a) if the class features appeal to you, or Battle Dancer 1 if you just want to get straight back to being a Bard.

As for general bard-friendly SADness, useful things are the Snowflake Wardance feat from Frostburn (which will allow you to add CHA to attack) and the Gauntlets of Heartfelt Blows (+CHA fire damage on attacks) from Dragon Compendium. You could also consider a Paladin dip for CHA to saves, using the Paladin of Freedom alternate class from Unearthed Arcana.

My bard optimization usually uses these tools as bonuses to focus on Inspire Courage optimization, for which there is [a handbook](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=9830).